# Soap Serializer does not support serializing Generic Types

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, soap

I have encountered an error, while trying to create soap message in C# Class.

**Booking Class-**

```
public class GuestDetails
    {
        public string GuestTitle { get; set; }
        public string GuestName { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }
        public string Pincode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookingDetails
    {
        public string BookingNumber { get; set; }
        public string BookingDate { get; set; }
        public string Bookedby { get; set; }
        public string OTAId { get; set; }
        public string OTAName { get; set; }
        public string BookingStatus { get; set; }
        public string CheckinDate { get; set; }
        public string CheckinTime { get; set; }
        public string CheckoutDate { get; set; }
        public string CheckoutTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoomingDetail
    {
        public string RoomTypeId { get; set; }
        public string RateId { get; set; }
        public string NoOfRooms { get; set; }
        public string Adult { get; set; }
        public string Children { get; set; }
        public string NoOfExtrabed { get; set; }
        public string MealPlan { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hotel
    {
        public string hotelid { get; set; }
        public GuestDetails GuestDetails { get; set; }
        public BookingDetails BookingDetails { get; set; }
        public List<RoomingDetail> RoomingDetails { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string accessKey { get; set; }
        public string channelId { get; set; }
        public List<Hotel> hotels { get; set; }
    }
```

**Converting C# class to Soap -**

```
    RootObject R = new RootObject();
    R.accessKey = "";
    R.channelId = "";
    R.hotels = new List<Hotel>();
    Hotel _hotel = new Hotel();
    _hotel.hotelid = "3";
    _hotel.GuestDetails = new GuestDetails();
    _hotel.GuestDetails.GuestName = "GuestName";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.GuestTitle = "GuestTitle";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.Nationality = "Nationality";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.PhoneNo = "PhoneNo";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.Pincode = "Pincode";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.Address1 = "Address1";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.Address2 = "Address2";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.Address3 = "Address3";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.Country = "Country";
    _hotel.GuestDetails.EmailId = "EmailId";
    _hotel.RoomingDetails = new List<RoomingDetail>();
    RoomingDetail _roomingDetails = new RoomingDetail();
    _roomingDetails.Adult = "1";
    _roomingDetails.Children = "2";
    _roomingDetails.MealPlan = "sds";
    _roomingDetails.NoOfExtrabed = "";
    _roomingDetails.NoOfRooms = "1";
    _roomingDetails.RateId = "222";
    _roomingDetails.RoomTypeId = "11";
    _hotel.RoomingDetails.Add(_roomingDetails);

    _hotel.BookingDetails = new BookingDetails();
    //BookingDetails _bookingDetails = new BookingDetails();
    _hotel.BookingDetails.Bookedby = "Jagadees";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.BookingDate = "05-08-2014";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.BookingNumber = "15999";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.BookingStatus = "Success";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.CheckinDate = "03-09-2014";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.CheckinTime = "";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.CheckoutDate = "05-09-2014";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.CheckoutTime = "";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.OTAId = "";
    _hotel.BookingDetails.OTAName = "";



    R.hotels.Add(_hotel);

    var r = new Random();
    SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();

    string myTempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), r.Next() + "SaveFile.txt");

    GC.SuppressFinalize(myTempFile);

    Stream objfilestream = new FileStream(myTempFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    formatter.Serialize(objfilestream, R); <-- ERROR HERE -->
    objfilestream.Close();
```

**Error -**

> SerializationException was ungandled by user code
>   Soap Serializer does not support serializing Generic Types :
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SoapwbApp.Hotel].

Comment: You will probably need to serialize it yourself then if it doesnt support it

Comment: Try changing List to Array. EG:  List<RoomingDetail> RoomingDetails to  RoomingDetail[] RoomingDetails.

Comment: have you thought using the `[Serializable]` on the classes..?
http://www.functionx.com/csharp2/serialization/soap.htm 
make sure this is in your using as well 
`using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;`

Comment: I think so. I serialize manually after checking all the possibilities . @ vajura

Comment: @bit I have tried with the array,. but the soap has't come fully.

Comment: @DJKRAZE after your command I put [Serializable] in all classes and I am using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap; only., but  I can't get the value parameter values in Soap xml message,.